# Is it possible to have delegation in user login?

Tags: 2010

I have a site with various workflows linked with InfoPath forms... Is it possible to have a delegation like thing such that.... another user can perform his task in his username...???

Comment: Why? That's the beauty of SharePoint, you can't simply act as someone else, its all you. What is the requirement for?

Comment: i have a workflow... some people .. who do not have the access to the network... cannot approve... Instead they require another person to impersonate them...

Comment: so the user that has to do the approving isn't a user in the system? maybe you should revisit the business process... if you want someone else to approve for them, assign it to that person.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :)

But it's custom development, you need to store the UserToken of the one you want to impersonate and then use this token to open the site and perform the action you want.

It's not going to be easy, but it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

There are some workarounds. For example, add user and substitudes in one SharePoint group and grant items permissions for this group at item added event of event receiver.